# Line space in outlook

Tags: html, css, html-email

While designing the email, I am getting extra space in outlook desktop client 2007 and newer versions. How can I get rid of them

```
<table>
    <tr><td style="%%=v(@h1R)=%% margin-top: 10px; padding: 10px 0 0 0;mso-padding: 10px 0 0 0;">Almost done!<td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><td style="%%=v(@paragraphBoldR)=%% margin-top: 10px;padding: 10px 0 0 0;mso-padding: 10px 0 0 0;"><b>Please finish submitting your reimbursement request.</b></td></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is this extra space?

Comment: after every <td> eg: between almost and please

Comment: Is it not the padding?

Comment: try `line-height: 20px; mso-line-height: exactly; line-height: 150%;`.  Substitute the line height (not mso-line-hight) with the line height from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does recognize padding on `<td>`. Try removing `mso-padding: 10px 0 0 0;`. That should remove 10px from the top.

Comment: I removed mso-padding and there is no change in spaces between lines.

Comment: You shouldn't really need all of those declarations just for some spacing. To further Gwally's point, remove all margin and mso-padding and just leave the padding:10px 0 0 0. To be honest, you could even shorten it to padding-top:10px, no need to declare all property values. Margin also shouldn't really make a difference but it makes no sense and should be removed either way.

Comment: I would also check the line heights of these sections... Typically, I'll take my font size and add 5px on to that and that gives me my line height, e.g. style="font-size:5px; line-height:10px;". Let us know how that goes, after doing that.

Comment: Whoop! Nice one.